# CSS horizontal dropdown menu shows up on hover in FF, but not IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to create a dropdown menu using straight CSS.  When you hover over the menu in Firefox, the dropdown shows up perfectly.  In IE7, the dropdown doesn't show up at all.  For the life of me, I cannot figure out why.

CSS is here: http://pastebin.com/eiWndMeq

Demo: http://www.josephruscitti.com/client-concept/niki/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the CSS you provided](http://pastebin.com/eiWndMeq), changing `top: auto;` to `top: 20px;` on line 57 works in IE7. Seems that IE7 just needs a little bit more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

add a 1 px transparent image to the background-image to your drop down. It's a hack that will fix the drop down for IE.